# Modal closes automatically - Angular

Tags: angular

```
  <div class="row-4">
     <button (click)="open(content)">Open modal</button>
     <ng-template #content>
     <p>HI</p>
     </ng-template>              
     </div>

 open(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, { class: 'modal-sm' });
  }
```

After 1 second of displaying the modal it redirects me to the other view.

Comment: Try with: `<button type="button" (click)="open(content)">Open modal</button>`

Comment: Thanks it works hahaha thanks again